# Geeting data from post in PHP and insert into table

Tags: php

I am getting data from iphone using php but when i insert post data in table it gives error

```
   mysql_select_db("emriphone", $con);

   $providernpi=$_POST['ProviderNPI'];
  $patienid=$_POST['PatientID'];
  $fileurl=$_POST['FileURL'];
 $filetype=$_POST['FileTYPE'];
 $datasynid=$_POST['DataSynID'];





$query = "INSERT into AppointmentDataSync      (ProviderNPI,PatientID,FileURL,FileType,DataSyncID) VALUES('$providernpi','$patientid','$fileurl','$filetype','$datasynid')"

 $con = mysql_query($query,$con);
$cnt  = mysql_num_rows($con);
echo($providernpi)
  ?>
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Try to check the POST parameters using isset, or if.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in <b>/home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/

Comment: I have to join the voices: what error?? And about how you build your query: it's not a good idea, it's sql injection prone!

Comment: I can't see the $ in the datasynid=$_POST['DataSynID'];  ;; good formatting of the code may also help to read it more easily and so identifying problems more easily, with a glance...

Comment: yes it is given in script i type here wrong in hurry

Comment: why you haven't simply copy-pasted it?? is there in the error message the line number too? if you can run php from cli, try the -l option: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query statement will be like this

```
$query = "INSERT into AppointmentDataSync      (ProviderNPI,PatientID,FileURL,FileType,DataSyncID) VALUES('".$providernpi."','".$patientid."','".$fileurl."','".$filetype."','".$datasynid."')";
```

EDIT

```
mysql_query($query);
printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Comment: i have done like this but now gives another error mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use `mysql_affected_rows()`. Please see [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: if i am giving mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link then it gives this error again

Comment: it shows now record inserted one

Comment: thanks it worked for me problem is that it gets 0 values for provider npi and patient id instead of real ids which are

Comment: Is the provider npi and patient id are `varchar` in database table. If these these two accept string as value and table fields have `int` as type can cause this error

Comment: in data base provider npi and patient id are var char

Comment: both are var char in the data base table

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few semicolons, for example after the `$query = ...` and `echo(...)` statements. A syntax error always means there's something wrong with how you wrote the code, not with the functionality of the code. Just looking carefully at the area around the line number given in the error messages solves most of them.

As for your other problem: `mysql_num_rows()` complaining about its argument not being a resource means your query has gone wrong. You should check whether the query was executed successfully (`$con` will evaluate to `true` then) and if not, check `mysql_error()` to get an error message.

By the way, your code is wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection). An attacker could insert some unexpected stuff in the POST parameters and your entire database will be leaked or manipulated in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Jusnit as told to insert query as he has given now it says mysql_num_rows supplied argument is invalid

Comment: @user1285130 see my updated answer, you should add some error handling code. Also, Jusnit is right about `mysql_affected_rows` (though probably you don't need it at all, just check if the query succeeds).

Comment: @Anohter Code my code is working fine but it insert o in patiendid and provider npi id